# A conjecture about matrices of integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Call two integers $a$ and $b$ *associated with respect to $n$* iff $a \mid nb$ and $b \mid na$. I have a theory that:

> **Conjecture.** Let $A$ denote a square matrix of (positive) integers. Then any two entries of $A$ that share either a row or a column are associated with respect to $\mathrm{det}(A)$.

Anyone know if this is actually true?

Comment: You're using "n" in two different ways -- to denote the determinant (in the "associated with respect to" definition), and to denote the size of the matrix. You might want to replace the "n" in the definition of "associated with respect to" with a "k", for instance, for clarity.

Comment: @JohnHughes, good thinking.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading.  Let $A= \left[\begin{matrix}
        3 & 2   \\
        1 & 1  \\
         
        \end{matrix}\right]$.  then $\det A=1$ but $2,3$ are not $1-$ associated.

Comment: What if some entry is $0$?

Comment: Perhaps every number divides 0? :)

Comment: I think you must have left off some conditions.  Obviously a matrix with determinant $1$, say, can have $1$ as an entry...but your conjecture would then mean that you believe that every other entry would then have to be $\pm 1$ which is clearly false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's false. 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 3 \\ 2 & 7}.
$$
Determinant is $1$, but $1$ and $3$ are not associated with respect to $+1$, even though they share a row.

Answer (score 1):

False, sorry. $$
  M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 2 & 3\\
   0& 1& 0\\
 0&0&1\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
2 and 3 share a row but are not associated with respect to det(M), which is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Take $I_2$. Its determinant is $1$ but $0$ does not divide $1$.